# How would I convert a cmake kde package to a deb source format

Tags: 22.04, packaging, cmake, source

So I want to convert the package [plank-player](https://invent.kde.org/plasma-bigscreen/plank-player) to Debian source
to be easily compiled, the package uses CMake.

Note I do not know what else to put in here so yay if your info ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These just hints as such procedure is getting automated and integrated  more and more. Each year I become like villager in the town :)

- CMake level: Start with [CPack](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CPack.html)
- Debian level: Follow [packaging guide/workflow](https://packaging.ubuntu.com/singlehtml/) for debugging and uploading

CMake w/CPack will prepare Debian source package (`debian` folder). Then rest is like any Debian package. If i remember well `dh` is the selected debian helper (by CPack) in `debian/rules` to help you debug.